# Need xunit test case for signalR trigger with Kafka

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, azure-functions, signalr, xunit

I have 2 methods in my azure functions

1. SignalR to Kafka - which writes data to Kafka using httptrigger
2. Kafka to signalR-which reads data from Kafka using kafkatrigger

I want to write xunit test cases for both the methods

Comment: Sounds great. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Without some sample code, its difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.